# Is this MVC Fire and Forget approach bad Design?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, asynchronous, fire-and-forget

I have a controller's action that performs a task and at the end, it sends a confirmation e-mail to the user. The e-mail part of it is not very important, so I do not want to make my action break if the sending of the e-mail throws an exception, and I don't want my HTTP response to wait for the e-mail to be sent either. I want this to be a fire and forget thing.


In a nutshell, this is how I approached it:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(){
    // Do stuff
    await DoStuff();        

    Thread sendEmailThread = new Thread(SendEmail);
    sendEmailThread.Start();

    return result;
}

private async void SendEmail(){
    await smtpClient.SendMessageAsync();
}
```

Is this approach proper?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to start a new Thread whenever a new email is arrived.

### Alternative Approach (especially for Email)

We normally run a background scheduling system behind the application. For example, Quartz.NET

Then we queue email in a queue (or database), and let the background thread pick up from queue (or database), and preform the process.

By doing so, we can re-send emails if SMTP has an error.

Comment: Why is it bad to start a short lasting thread that sends an e-mail from a specific HTTP request?

Comment: If SMTP has an error, the thread will be idle *(until you receive the exception such as System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.)* If the application receives a lot of emails and SMTP has an error, you will end up with idle threads. In additions, you'll lose all those failed emails. In contrast, scheduling approach uses thread more efficiently, and you can re-send those failed emails.

Comment: What do you mean by idle? If an exception is not caught in the new thread, wouldn't that thread just terminate? Also, in this specific case I don't mind if the e-mail is lost.

Comment: `If an exception is not caught in the new thread, wouldn't that thread just terminate?` It is true. However, it takes a while to receive the exception back when you are dealing with Network problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to start a new thread for sending the email as that method will return as soon as the `async` operation is kicked off and the thread will end before the operation is complete.

Async operations [do not use a thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) so you are best off to just return a `Task` from that method and `await` it. Async `void` returning methods are a bad idea as well as no exceptions propagate out of them and you can't tell when the operation is completed. See [Best Practices in Async programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more details.

If you really want to do a fire and forget task, see [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) on the subject.

Comment: I have to put it in a separate thread because MVC would not allow me to have a pending task left running after the action is done.
<br/>
<br/>
Your suggestion would make the action (and thus the HTTP response) wait for the email to be sent. This is not the behavior I want. I want the HTTP response to finish even if the email hasn't been sent yet.

Comment: Then you can remove the `await` and just call `SendMail()`

Comment: Can't. MVC complains at run time with an exception to the client that there's a task left running after the action returned. Also, you get an expected warning at compile time about not awaiting a task.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a direct solution but the fire and forget thing is implemented by open source eCommerce solution for asp.net and is called nopCommerce. I really love their solution, i just wanted to share it with you. 
Here is the codeplex code;

Go to **Src -> Libraries -> Nop.Services -> Tasks** 

https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Libraries/Nop.Services/Tasks/TaskManager.cs

Now have a look at the TaskManager class. You can check the demo online [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/demo.aspx).
Go to **Admin Panel -> System Menu -> Schedule Tasks**

#### Explanation

They are using this class as queue emails, keep alive, clear caching, exchange rates auto update and deleting many other things. And it works exactly you wanted. If any exception occurs, it will just retry and it won't stop or break the app. You can check the demo.